# regex get id imgur embed?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am still learning to use regex; I tried going through other similar threads but they didn't help.

Here is my regex for embedded iframe for imgur.com: https://regex101.com/r/qI4lY7/1

```
(https?:\/\/imgur\.com\/a\/(.*?)(?:\/)?)
```

How can I get the complete id?

Specimen URLs (taken from linked regex101):

- `http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j/embed#0`
- `http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j#0`
- `http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j`
- `http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j/all`
- `http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j/embed?backgrou...umbs=true`

What the? downvote to 3 ?

Comment: The id of all these URLs is the `ksU2j`, I assume?

Comment: The id that you are telling is `ksU2j`?

Comment: yes for get id **ksU2j**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below regex and then get the id from group index 2 and url from index 1.

```
(https?:\/\/imgur\.com\/a\/(.*?)(?:[#\/].*|$))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qI4lY7/2)

Here the trickier part is by adding `$` end of the line anchor. So `(.*?)` captures all the characters upto the `/` or `#` symbol if there is such symbol present after to `/a` or it would capture all the characters upto the end of the line.

```
> var s = 'http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j/embed#0'
undefined
> /https?:\/\/imgur\.com\/a\/(.*?)(?:[#\/].*|$)/.exec(s)
[ 'http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j/embed#0',
  'ksU2j',
  index: 0,
  input: 'http://imgur.com/a/ksU2j/embed#0' ]
```

Comment: i explained...... you could see step by step explanation at the right side in the above demo link.

Comment: hy this almost perfect, but in MATCH 2 isnt good `ksU2j#0` please your help :)

Comment: did you want to exclude the `#0` part? if yes then try this https://regex101.com/r/qI4lY7/3

Comment: yes sir, working perfectly. i love you. Thxx for helping. upvote is coming .. 

BTW why my post have downvote up to 3 times? T__T please upvote for me :D